# How can i set this array's type in typescript

Tags: typescript

i'm migrate the Javascript to typescript.
i have a data that has bottom type

```js
[{name:"poo",total:1},
[{title:"wow", day:20220201,poster:"*.jpg"},{...},...],
[{},{}...],....]
```

this array's 0 index has object key is name and total and 1to max num has array that has object title, day, poster and same 10 object is in

and this array'1,2....max' has same pattern and max is decided dynamic

and how to decide the type of that array

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with typeScript, you could use an interface to create a custom type of data for your array.

you could use something like that:

```
interface myType{
   name?:string;
   total?:number;
   element_3?:string;
   element_4?:string;
 }



let your_array:Array<myType>=[];
```